# jQuery - How to clone the last row line

Tags: jquery

I want to clone the last row line and have the following HTML/jQuery code like this :

```
 <script>
 $('#driver_button').click(function () {
        $('form > .driver_row:last').clone().insertAfter('form > .driver_row:last');
    });
 </script>

 <form .... >
   <div class="row driver_row">
   ...
   </div>
  <div class="row driver_row">
   ...
  </div>
  <div class="row driver_row">
   ...
  </div>
  <button id="driver_button" type="button">
  </button>

  <div class="row">
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Save">
  </div>
</form>
```

Sometime it works and sometime it clones multiple times the last line.
Any clue ?

Answer (score 1):

I slightly corrected your script in my "own" way and it seemed to be working fine for me, when I tested it. And you also have to remember to load your script after DOM is loaded, the script didn't work in code snippet until I moved it after `html` part

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="form">
   <div class="row driver_row">
   ...
   </div>
  <div class="row driver_row">
   ...
  </div>
  <div class="row driver_row">
   ...
  </div>
</form>
<button id="driver_button" type="button"> click
</button>
<div class="row">
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Save">
</div>
<script>
$('#driver_button').click(function () {
 $(".driver_row:last").clone().appendTo('#form');
});
</script>
```

Comment: what is the mistake you corrected? and why the script must follow the code?

Comment: Oh thanks, looks good. But I have of course a submit button, and I want to insert the copied line before this submit button.

Comment: @SvenKirsten you need to load your script after loading a document.  follow this link for more details. https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/